How to easily expose endpoints in a format like Spring Data REST?
I use spring-data-rest in a project and it generates hundreds of endpoints, but whenever I create an endpoint manually I struggle to make all those links to all the entities, is there an easy way to do this?
My goal is to make endpoints that match the format generated by spring-data-rest, that respects HAL using HATEOAS.

For implementing custom endpoints, the links need to be assigned individually.
For generating the links you can utilize the WebMvcLinkBuilder as documented here
The links are usually added inside the implementation of a RepresentationModelAssembler or PagedModelAssembler.
